Context of Quote by Edward Nelson
Those in the right circles, and especially the mathematical physicists, will know the statement: “First quantization is a mystery, but second quantization is a functor,” supposedly by Edward Nelson. It’s been quoted by John Baez and in this arXiv book in Chapter 4. However, much as with many quotes, if the person alleged to have said it even did, the original context is not kept with the quote. I’ve done some basic searching, but I have found no luck on if Edward Nelson actually said this and, if so, when and where.
Thus, did Edward Nelson actually say this? Of course, this might just be an impossible task.

It's used as an epigraph to section X.7 of vol 2 of Reed and Simon's Methods of Mathematical Physics, on free quantum fields.  I the notes to that section do not give a more precise attribution.

See http://math.caltech.edu/papers/bsimon/xliv.pdf and "The Free Markoff Field" by E. Nelson, Journal of Functional Analysis 12(1973)211-227. The title of section 2 of the latter is "Second Quantization as a Functor".

This is not answer, but a note on where and what to expect for an answer.
In the enlarged English edition of his book Noncommutative Geometry (Academic Press, 1994), Alain Connes cites the saying literatim and with the remark "a saying attributed to E. Nelson" (in the 1990 French edition, it does not exist):

If even Alain Connes did not know the original source of the saying, I presume, it can be hardly expected to be found in print.
Of course, there is still the possibility that it will occur in someone's memoir.
